# Weird characters in string

Tags: python

I am reading some data from file..

But there are some weird characters I am observing like;

```
'tamb\xc3\xa9m', 'f\xc3\xbcr','cari\xc3\xb1o'
```

My file read code is fairly standard:

```
 with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have UTF-8 encoded data. You could decode the data:

```
with open(filename) as f:
   for line in f:
       print line.decode('utf8')
```

or use [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) to have Python decode the contents for you, as you read:

```
import io

with io.open(filename, encoding='utf8') as f:
   for line in f:
       print line
```

Your data, decoded:

```
>>> print 'tamb\xc3\xa9m'.decode('utf8')
também
>>> print 'f\xc3\xbcr'.decode('utf8')
für
>>> print 'cari\xc3\xb1o'.decode('utf8')
cariño
```

You appear to have printed string *representations*, (the output of the `repr()` function), which produces string literal syntax suitable for pasting back into your Python interpreter. `\xhh` hex codes are used for characters outside of the printable ASCII range. Python containers such as `list` or `dict` also use `repr()` to show their contents, when printed.

You may want to read up on Unicode, and how it interacts with Python. See:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder